# convert pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert this Timestamp object to datetime this object was obtained after using asfreq on a dataframe this is the last index

```
Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

wanted output

```
2018-12-01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you want this?

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps import Timestamp
ts = Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')
date_time = ts.to_pydatetime()
```

And if you just want a string then you can do this:

```
print(str(ts).split()[0])
```

out:

```
'2018-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to *floor* the timestamp upto the date part (or any other part), which in this example will get rid of the hour-minute-second level detail.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:10:10')]})  
df.ts.dt.floor('d')
0   2019-01-01
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```